# Duplicate Resources: Is there a way to ignore the duplicate resource automatically while building in android studio

Tags: android, xml, duplicates, resources

I have 2 res folder but not in the same path,and with each of res folder which has a values folder.
In values folder, there is a "string.xml" file. (See the pictures below).
Inside of each of "string.xml" file, there are 2 string names which defined similarly. When I build the project, i get this errors:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     [string/app_name] E:\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml   [string/app_name] E:\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\src\main\java\com\example\quywn\test\res\values\string.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Of course with only 2 string.xml file, I can rename or delete it manually, but when I have a lot of files with the same error above, I can't rename or delete them manually. So my question is "Is there a way to rename/delete the content inside of duplicate resources or ignore duplicate resource and just choose 1 of the same content automatically ?"

For example: I have 2 string.xml with the same defined string name inside of each of string.xml. When building, the system checks the 2 file string.xml and just choose 1 string name and ignore the other although the one of 2 string names is not deleted or renamed. And at this time, I expect that error will not occurs and build successfully.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k9Ag.png)

[The content of the first string.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLEeP.png)

[The content of the second string.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsZZg.png)

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to do something similarly to add multi language support in android. 
you have same string name in string.xml and you want to use one of them. look at this 
[link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages), it might helps you.